# I am having become True in playbook of ansible still received not a root user

Tags: ansible, rhel

I am trying to remove package but received not a root error.
I have rhel 7.4 running on EC2 instance.

```yaml
---
- hosts: ec2_rhel
  #become_user: funnel
  become: yes
  tasks:  
    - name: Email server package installation
      yum:
        name: "@E-mail Server"
        state: absent
```

Error:

```
ASK [Email server package installation] ****************************************************************************************************
fatal: [52.53.174.227]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "changes": {"removed": ["@E-mail Server"]}, "msg": "Repo rhui-client-config-server-7 forced skip_if_unavailable=True due to: /etc/pki/rhui/cdn.redhat.com-chain.crt\nRepo rhui-client-config-server-7 forced skip_if_unavailable=True due to: /etc/pki/rhui/product/rhui-client-config-server-7.crt\nRepo rhui-client-config-server-7 forced skip_if_unavailable=True due to: /etc/pki/rhui/rhui-client-config-server-7.key\nRepo rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms forced skip_if_unavailable=True due to: /etc/pki/rhui/cdn.redhat.com-chain.crt\nRepo rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms forced skip_if_unavailable=True due to: /etc/pki/rhui/product/content-rhel7.crt\nRepo rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms forced skip_if_unavailable=True due to: /etc/pki/rhui/content-rhel7.key\nRepo rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms forced skip_if_unavailable=True due to: /etc/pki/rhui/cdn.redhat.com-chain.crt\nRepo rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms forced skip_if_unavailable=True due to: /etc/pki/rhui/product/content-rhel7.crt\nRepo rhel-7-server-rhui-rh-common-rpms forced skip_if_unavailable=True due to: /etc/pki/rhui/content-rhel7.key\nYou need to be root to perform this command.\n", "rc": 1, "results": ["Loaded plugins: amazon-id, search-disabled-repos\n"]}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************
              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually in the host file I have put ansible_become_user which is not part of admin or root privilege. When I comment out ansible_become_user and ansible_become_pass from host file, above playbook work with root user.

Is there any way to login with root privilege user and change a user for one or two tasks?